# iOS swipe left to right to previous page with gesture effect example

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

Currently, I did when user go back previous page they have two options to do. 
1. Click back button
2. Swipe left to right

Both function called following code to go back previous page.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But my client want gesture effect which is included in iOs7 onward as per following image. Please let me know how to solve that feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a UIPageViewController. However that is a different form of navigation than pushing/popping onto a navigation controller.

If you want to trigger pushes/pops you will need to attach a pan gesture recognized to your view, and then implement a custom view controller transition.